# How to delete duplicates in excel in different situations (VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to sum corresponding values in to the right columns, but also delete duplicates. Here's the deal:

If, for example, I have columns from A to F. If columns A to E are the same with another row, macro deletes the row and saves older one. 
IF columns A to C are same with another existing row, macro deletes another row and adds those corresponding values from column D and E to the remaining row. Here is an example:

```
cell1 cell2 cell3 cell4 cell5 cell6
1      1     1     1     1     1
2      2     2     2     2     2
2      2     2     2     2     2
1      1     1     2     2     1
3      3     3     3     3     3

After macro:

cell1  cell2 cell3 cell4 cell5 cell6
1      1     1      3     3     1 
2      2     2      2     2     2
3      3     3      3     3     3
```

So now, macro has deleted row 4 (because it has same values on column A to C as row 1 has) an adds corresponding values from columns D and E to row 1. Also, rows 2 and 3 are duplicates from column A to E, so macro deletes row 3.

Here is an example what I have tried (I got help before with sum-problem (from @JvdV) and adding corresponding values in to right ones works, but I don't know, how to remove duplicates correctly..)

Class module:

```
Public Col1 As Variant
Public Col2 As Variant
Public Col3 As Variant
Public Col4 As Variant
Public Col5 As Variant
Public Col6 As Variant
```

Module:

```
Dim x As Long, arr As Variant, lst As Class1
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheet1
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:F" & x).Value
End With

.Range("A1:F" & x).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Header:=xlYes

For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3)) Then
        Set lst = New Class1
        lst.Col1 = arr(x, 1)
        lst.Col2 = arr(x, 2)
        lst.Col3 = arr(x, 3)
        lst.Col4 = arr(x, 4)
        lst.Col5 = arr(x, 5)
        lst.Col6 = arr(x, 6)
        dict.Add arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3), lst
    Else
        dict(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3)).Col4 = dict(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3)).Col4 + arr(x, 4)
        dict(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3)).Col5 = dict(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3)).Col5 + arr(x, 5)
    End If
Next x

With Sheet1
    x = 1
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        .Cells(x, 1).Value = dict(Key).Col1
        .Cells(x, 2).Value = dict(Key).Col2
        .Cells(x, 3).Value = dict(Key).Col3
        .Cells(x, 4).Value = dict(Key).Col4
        .Cells(x, 5).Value = dict(Key).Col5
        .Cells(x, 6).Value = dict(Key).Col6
        x = x + 1
    Next Key
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You claim you check `A:E` but the code seems to check `A:C` (`dict.Exists(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3))`). Can you clarify it?

Comment: First thing to notice in your code is that you have used `.Range("A1:F" & x).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Header:=xlYes` outside the `With` statement. Also, you have included column F (which equals 6 in the array) but you would only need 1-5. You also populated the `arr` before you have cleared out the unneccesary duplicates. Haven't checked other parts of the code yet =)

Comment: Hi @user3819867 :) that is because if columns a to c are the same, then corresponding values from columns d and e sums up and deletes another row.. But if columns from a to e are the same, then it just deletes duplicate row and doesn't sum anything. Hopefully i explained clearly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some mistakes in your code, including populating your array before deleting first duplicates and having your `RemoveDuplicates` outside your `With` statement and including column F. To make your code work properly you could try the below:

***<sub>Before</sub>***

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim x As Long, arr As Variant, lst As Class1
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheet1

    'Step one: Delete duplicates over columns A-E
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:F" & x).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Header:=xlYes

    'Step two: Populate your array
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A2:F" & x).Value

    'Step three: Clear range
    .Range("A2:F" & x).ClearContents

    'Step Four: Go through your array and populate a dictionary
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Set lst = New Class1
        lst.Col1 = arr(x, 1)
        lst.Col2 = arr(x, 2)
        lst.Col3 = arr(x, 3)
        lst.Col4 = arr(x, 4)
        lst.Col5 = arr(x, 5)
        lst.Col6 = arr(x, 6)
        KeyX = Join(Array(arr(x, 1), arr(x, 2), arr(x, 3)), "|")
        If dict.Exists(KeyX) = False Then
            dict.Add KeyX, lst
        Else
            dict(KeyX).Col4 = dict(KeyX).Col4 + arr(x, 4)
            dict(KeyX).Col5 = dict(KeyX).Col5 + arr(x, 5)
        End If
    Next x

    'Step five: Go through your dictionary and write to sheet
    x = 2
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        .Range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x, 6)).Value = Array(dict(key).Col1, dict(key).Col2, dict(key).Col3, dict(key).Col4, dict(key).Col5, dict(key).Col6)
        x = x + 1
    Next key

End With

End Sub
```

***<sub>After</sub>***

[image]

Let me know how it went =)

Comment: Hi @JvdV :) You have helped me so much with these codes, I really really appreciate it!! Thank you. I tested this in my actual excel, where is 18 columns and 8000 rows. This code works so well in test excels, just how I want it to work, but when I run it in my actual excel, it somehow deletes almost every value on column 17 and moves some names from column 18 to 17.. Why is this. Should I post the edited version here :)?

Comment: sorry, my bad!! I had a typo and now it works :) thank you once again!

Comment: Well actualle, there is one question @JvdV :) (after all, haha) When I run the code from the VBA 'bar' it works, but if I click after that from the excels command button, it deletes every value from the table.. why is this?

Comment: Hello @Emppunen, I'm not quite sure what you mean with that. Would all data get deleted on a second run?

Comment: Yes, if I run it second time it deletes all the data (and this doesnt happen when I run it in a test excel, just in an actual excel).. @JvdV

Comment: I try to explain better. When I run the code in Visual basic program, it works correctly. If I try to press after this command button, it deletes every value from my table and gives me an error code *type mismatch*. But I dont have this problem in my test excel, only in this actual one :D

Comment: I am drawing a complete blank here I'm afraid. I would have no clue as to why that would happen in your real sheet. Only suggestion I have is to make sure your references are 100% correct. @emppunen

Comment: Im sorry @JvdV , what do you mean with references? :)

Comment: @emppunen, all references made to sheets, ranges, column numbers etc etc. If you really can't figure it out maybe post your excel in your original question for people to have a look (allthough it's not recommended)

Comment: Can I ask from the code @JvdV :) What is that clear.contents command? What it actually does? I didnt quite understand when I googled it. AND if I populate my dictionary, should I add every column there, or just those which I 'use'. Hopefully I explained it clearly :)

Comment: Now I deleted the clear.contents part 3 from my code and it doesnt delete every value in the table anymore on the second run. But no if I run it second time, it gives me type mismatch and highlights this part: KeyX = Join(Array(arr(x, 1), arr(x, 2), arr(x, 3), arr(x, 4), arr(x, 5), arr(x, 6)), "|")

Comment: @emppunen, `ClearContents` simply deletes the contents from the given range. This makes sure that the new data is not superseded by information that should not be there.