# Return array of class properties from dictionary

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, class, dictionary

***<sub>Background:</sub>***

While recently trying to answer a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58835358/9758194), I had myself thinking if it would be possible to return an array of class object properties directly from a dictionary item.

***<sub>Code:</sub>***

Imagine `TstClass` as a class module with the following code:

```
Public val1 As Variant
Public val2 As Variant
Public val3 As Variant
```

Then this code to test:

```
Sub Test()

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim lst As TstClass, key As Variant, arr As Variant

For x = 1 To 3
    Set lst = New TstClass
    lst.val1 = "A" & x
    lst.val2 = "B" & x
    lst.val3 = "C" & x
    dict.Add x, lst
Next x

For Each key In dict
    arr = Array(dict(key).val1, dict(key).val2, dict(key).val3)
Next key

End Sub
```

***<sub>Problem:</sub>***

In the above case `Array(dict(key).val1, dict(key).val2, dict(key).val3)` will return the array just fine, but if we imagine `val4-val50` it will become a lot more code. Either with `Array(...)` or writing it out line by line `Debug.Print Dict(key).Valx`.

***<sub>Question:</sub>***

Is it possible to return an array directly from the class object properties from the dictionary key? The most obvious thing to try for me was `arr = Dict(key)` hoping it would somehow recognize I needed all properties from the item. On top of that it's not allowed to declare Constants, Arrays, User Defined Types as Public, so something like `Public Vals(0 to 2)` won't work either.

Thank you,
JvdV

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is *exactly* what you are after, but it is possible to make a method inside your class that would build an array of the properties you desire. You can then call that on each of the instances of the class to get the array details.

**Class - named 'Example':**

```
Public val1 As Variant
Public val2 As Variant
Public val3 As Variant

Public Function GetArray() As Variant
    GetArray = Array(Me.val1, Me.val2, Me.val3)
End Function
```

**Client Code - In a Standard Module:**

```
Sub SOExample()

    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim lst As Example, arr As Variant, key As Variant

    For x = 1 To 3
        Set lst = New Example
        lst.val1 = "A" & x
        lst.val2 = "B" & x
        lst.val3 = "C" & x
        dict.Add x, lst
    Next

    For Each key In dict.keys
        arr = dict(key).GetArray
        Debug.Print Join(arr, ",")
    Next

End Sub
```

**Output:**

```
A1,B1,C1
A2,B2,C2
A3,B3,C3
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Creating a method within the class seems to be as doing all the work (building an array) behind the scenes of the module. It's not quite what I'm after (which might not even exists).

Comment: I've taken the idea of creating a `Public Function` to return the array, but used another approach to build an `Private` array using `Property Let`. I've posted the answer. Please be welcome to provide feedback/ideas on how to improve. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: Yup, I hear you. The pro of this approach, is you only need to define this once.

Comment: It sounds you are trying to represent properties in a class as an array, I'm unaware of a direct way of doing this. I don't think Classes structure their data  like this, happy to be wrong though. If you want to dynamically reference properties in a Class, maybe the CallByName function  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/calling-a-property-or-method-using-a-string-name) would help?

Comment: Not really, as I'm fairly new to `Class` modules, I was looking for a way to reference their properties in a more dynamic way. And the `GetArray` idea of yours has taken me that step further in understanding it's stuctures which resulted in the attempt in my post =)

Answer (score 0):

Taken inspiration form the answer by @RyanWildry, I figured out that, despite being unable to use a `Public` variant array, we could use a `Private` one. Therefor, I made it such that [`Property Let`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/property-let-statement) would assign the value to a specific index within the array.

Creating a `Public Function` to return the `Private` array variable would then return the array in one go.

---

***<sub>Class module, named `TstClass`</sub>***

```
Private vals(0 To 2) As Variant

Public Property Let val(ByVal x As Long, ByVal NewVal As Variant)
    vals(x) = NewVal
End Property

Public Function GetArray() As Variant
    GetArray = vals
End Function
```

***<sub>Code under Module1</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim lst As TstClass, key As Variant, arr As Variant

For x = 1 To 3
    Set lst = New TstClass
    lst.val(0) = "A" & x
    lst.val(1) = "B" & x
    lst.val(2) = "C" & x
    dict.Add x, lst
Next x

For Each key In dict
    arr = dict(key).GetArray
Next key

End Sub
```

---

Another way would be to leave the idea of an `Class` module alone, and go with (for example) an `ArrayList` object:

```
Sub Test()

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim lst As Object: Set lst = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim arr As Variant

For x = 1 To 3
    lst.Add "A" & x
    lst.Add "B" & x
    lst.Add "C" & x
    dict.Add x, lst.Toarray
    lst.Clear
Next x

For Each key In dict
    arr = dict(key)
Next key

End Sub
```

However, the latter approach would surpass the purpose of this question.

This is as close as I can get as to returning an array directly from a dictionary item. I'm happy to recieve constructive feedback or other/better ways as `Class` modules are rather new to me and this still doesn't answer the essence of the question on how to return an array of the properties directly.